# SharePont 2019 Contact List email field showing mailto: url in the modern experience

Tags: list-view, modern-experience

In the SP2019 on-premise solution, the Contact List's email field (single line of text) will show the complete <A href=..." url in the field instead of just email. When I switch the list back to the classic experience, it would show normally. Is there a way to fix this if we would like to keep the Modern experience? Thanks!

[image: Modern Experience]

[image: CLassic Experience]

Comment: Did you change the column formatting using JSON? or is this the error with out of the box list view?

Comment: 2019 doesn't support JSON column formatting...

Comment: I can't reproduce this on the Feb 2021 PU with an out of the box list. The Modern experience just shows text w/o any form of link.

Comment: Disregard, this is for the OOTB Contact List template. Yes, can repro there. Looks like a product bug.

Comment: not able to produce in modern  sharepoint list

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the reply! The column isn't formatted using JSON. Also this is OOTB contact list. The list was created as classic experience. I later changed it to modern experience thru the list setting (advanced setting) just to keep experience the same across the board. I did not create a modern list, but that's probably what I'll do next. @TrevorSeward thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: Confirmed if I just create a modern list from scratch, the single line of text with email address would display normally. It's not a clickable link, but I can live with that.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed if I just create a modern list from scratch, the single line of text with email address would display normally. It's not a clickable link, but I can live with that.

Seems like the bug was due to using OOTB Contact List template as repro'ed by Trevor.

[image]